# Wp Rest Api request returns html not json format

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am working on Wp Rest API. I want to retrieve posts from WordPress site that result to display in another PHP site. I have created a rest url "http://sitename.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts" like this to get the posts. This request displays the data in html format but not in JSON format. I have tested two different URLs in PostMan application. How to get the API response into JSON format not html from WordPress site.

**This is My URL data**

[image]

**This is Thirdparty URL data**

[image]

Comment: Clear cache and remove plugin WP Super Cache

Comment: In postman, just change it to JSON in the dropdown. It autodetects the returned result. Since there's a lot of html in your response, it will auto format it to HTML.. You can still parse the results as per the documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/ Postman is just returning it incorrectly.

Comment: Tarang Koradiya your suggestion is worked.....Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Accept header in your request. If you are testing with Postman, add the following header:

This tells the server that you prefer JSON-formatted responses.

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" http://sitename.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

please hit your curl URL in this link to test it working fine with `Accept: application/json`

[**run curl online**](https://reqbin.com/curl)

please change your domain name in the place of http://sitename.com